# concat two data frames and keep no-common values adding a Na value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to contact two columns from independent data frames. There are some values in common (most of them) but not all of them. That is a simple command but how I want the output is what I do not know.

What I need is:

1. Common values one of each other
2. If one value from one dataset is not found in the other dataset add an indicator (e.g.: "Not found" or a null value is fine)
3. I don't want to lose or run out of any value.

Example.

```
first = pd.DataFrame({"id1": ["K0","K4" ])
second = pd.DataFrame({"id2": ["K0", "K2", "K3"], "v": [4, 6,3]})


# Output:

Id1       Id2
k0        k0
Not found K2
Not found K3
K4        Not found
...
```

According to the documentation, the command should be

```
pd.concat([first, second["id2"]],axis=1,)
```

But this returns something like

```
Id1       Id2
k0        k0
K3        K2
K4        Na
...
```

What I am doing wrong?

I have ensured that the values that match wrongly exist in both input columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try with merge

```
out = first.merge(second[['id2']],left_on='id1',right_on='id2',how='outer').fillna('not found')
Out[186]: 
         id1        id2
0         K0         K0
1         K4  not found
2  not found         K2
3  not found         K3
```